# How can make auto change in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, jobs

I want to make auto changes in SQL Server. I have a table which has a column `[expires date]`. Should I use a trigger or job for this? I want that SQL Server checks those dates every day, and if any of it is `< DateTime.Now`, it must change a column `[IsPremium]` of that row.

Comment: Please stop giving minus to question, if dont help at all its fine. But atleast dont troll it..

Comment: Use a SQL Job to do the same.

Comment: Question is unclear...

Comment: Since it's not an action that has to happen every time a row is inserted, updated or deleted, you shouldn't use a trigger, that would be the wrong solution. Since it has to be checked once a day -> it's a perfect match for a SQL Server Agent job that's run e.g. once at night, and updates the table as needed

Comment: Why not just define `IsPremium` as a computed column that has one value if expires date is in the future and a different value if its in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following statement in your **Daily running JOB**, if you have. (Your question in unclear. As per my understanding I post this)

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET
       IsPremium = 1
WHERE  [expires date] < GETDATE()
```